# Не работает автовыдача ролей Discord.py

Tags: python, discord

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if not payload.message_id == 766756019199410211:
        return
    if not payload.emoji.name == "":  
        return
    if member := payload.member:
        await member.add_roles(member.guild.get_role(758394776390336513))
```

Строчка кода, которая не работает.

Comment: Какую ошибку выводить?